# error while storing the value on the manual location using pointers on gcc

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *p;

    p = &a+2;

    // here p and &a+2 will going to be same...having some particular address on memory

    *p = 56;

    // m writing 56 on *(p) or *(&a+2)...

    printf("%d %d\n",*p,*(&a+2));

    return 0;
}
```

o/p showing me is what!! `*p = 56` but `*(&a+2)` = same as `&a+2`...

For `p = &a+1` it's giving me a stack smashing...

On `*(*(&a+2))` giving me the desired result `56`...

Can anyone explain to me what the exact reason behind this is?

Comment: It's not clear what output you were expecting and what output you actually got - please clarify this by providing a [mcve].

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings: https://ideone.com/vOCpGK.  This code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: *p i got is 56 and p is some address...so im writing 56 on that address so i should got 56 for *(&a+2) but i got the address not the value... in printf statement i got 56, some address ... instead of 56,56

Comment: Always turn on warnings!!! (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c99 a.c -o a && a`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = &a+2;
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
p = &(a[6]);
```

because adding two to `&a` adds `sizeof(a)*2` to `&a`, and `sizeof(a)*2` is equal to `sizeof(a[0])*3*2`. Dereferencing the resulting pointer evokes undefined behaviour because it's beyond the end of the array.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *p = &a+2;
    printf("a    @ %p\n", (void*)a);
    printf("a    @ %p\n", (void*)&a);
    printf("a[0] @ %p\n", (void*)&(a[0]));
    printf("a[2] @ %p\n", (void*)&(a[2]));
    printf("p    = %p\n", (void*)p);
    printf("a[6] @ %p\n", (void*)&(a[6]));
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c99 a.c -o a && a
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:5:14: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     int *p = &a+2;
              ^
a    @ 0x3878b9c3030
a    @ 0x3878b9c3030
a[0] @ 0x3878b9c3030
a[2] @ 0x3878b9c3038
p    = 0x3878b9c3048
a[6] @ 0x3878b9c3048
```

Comment: I think you mean "adds `sizeof(a)*2` to `&a`"

Comment: @Max, Thanks, fixed.

Comment: To be pedantic - they're only "equivalent" in the loosest sense - they're different types.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth, That's covered by the warning at the bottom. Changed to "functionally equivalent".

Comment: @Antti Haapala, Are you saying that `&a+2` is UB? Why?

Comment: @ikegami because the standard *explicitly* says so. [6.5.6p8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8)

Comment: @ikegami yes, that's how I read it. One past would work, as an object can be considered an array of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `p=a+2;`, not `p=&a+2;`.  The latter forms a pointer to the *array* `a` (with `&a`) and then tries to form a pointer to a non-existent other array (which would be a row in a multidimensional array if it existed).  Pointers to arrays are rarely used, which helps people confuse arrays and the pointers into which they [decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: no!! p = a+2 means &a[2]...means p = &a[2]..but i'm about &a+2...aannn..suppose &a[0] = 100, then im writing 56 on 124 by storing 124 on p.so I should get 56 for*(&a+2) !!

Comment: @RuchiM.Mewada - It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.  But `&a + 2` doesn't point to anywhere legal.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain to me what the exact reason behind this is?

The reasoning is that you are invoking undefined behavior, so your compiler and thus your program is allowed to do whatever the hell it wants. That is pretty much the definition of "undefined behavior": the standard doesn't say what the correct thing to do is, so the program can do anything.

Just because `*(*(&a+2))` gives you the right answer doesn't mean that `&a+2` is valid code. There are plenty of cases where undefined behavior can result in a working program, but there's no guarantee that such a program will continue to work or even continue to compile as you make further changes.

The undefined behavior, as several people have already pointed out, is from `p = &a+2` which assigns an uninitialized address to an incompatible pointer.